# Plot to show the progress on some process

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I have **n** repetitive process of optimisation which returns one single value or score after each optimisation is finished. I want to plot this value in a single plot every time one optimisation is finished, so the plot will shows the progress of the optimisation. It looks something like this:
[image]

I have tried to coded something like this:

```
progress_plot <- function(progress) {
plot(progress, xlab="n evaluations", ylab="scores")
}
```

and then I called it with like this

```
for(iter in 1:n){
iter <- 1
optimisation(process) ## this will return score
iter <- iter + 1
progress_plot(score)
score
}
```

I got an error message like this:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

What did I miss from here? 
Also, is that possible to have such a progress plot that can adjust its scale based on the range of the current maximum values of score?

Comment: Why are you doing `iter in 1:n` and also `iter <- iter + 1`? This is most likely a problem with the value of score and it's unlikely anybody can help you until you give a reproducible example.

Comment: This is not really how you loop in r... Don't reassign or increment iter within the loop. See `for(iter in 1:n){ print(iter) }` for details